# Ping output - epoch time to human readable

Tags: networking

I would like the time output from ping to be human readable, currently I get:

```
pingn -DO 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[1452885114.787974] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1
[1452885115.795961] no answer yet for icmp_seq=2
[1452885116.803959] no answer yet for icmp_seq=3
```

I have googled around, trying things like:

```
pingn -DO 10.0.0.1 | sed 's/(.*)(1[0-9]{9}.[0-9]6)(.*)/echo \1 $(date -d @\2 +"%d-%m-%Y %T %z") \3/e'
```

but I only get errors from sed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes:

- `[0-9]6` should be `[0-9]{6}`, which means match 6 `0-9` characters - the fractions of a second.
- You are using extended regular expressions, so you need to use the -r flag with sed, to avoid errors like:

  ```
  sed: -e expression #1, char 74: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS
  ```

The corrected commands are:

```
pingn -DO 10.0.0.1 | sed -r 's/(.*)(1[0-9]{9}.[0-9]{6})(.*)/echo \1 $(date -d @\2 +"%d-%m-%Y %T %z") \3/e'
```

And the output will be in this format:

```
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[ 16-01-2016 12:02:59 +0000 ] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.28 ms
[ 16-01-2016 12:03:00 +0000 ] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.678 ms
...
```

Note that `pingn` is not the normal command for ping.  Are you sure you don't mean `ping`?

Comment: yes, I have aliased pingn with ping -n

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, transforming the date with perl :

```
 ping -DO 8.8.8.8 |  perl -pe 's/(\d{10}.\d{6})/localtime($1)/e'
```

Similar to the sed expression, this uses 's/ / /' format.  The $1 is equivalent to sed's \1 .  localtime converts the numbers matched inside the escaped parentheses:
`\d{10}.\d{6}` is the epoch time (10 digits) with microseconds (6 digits) suffixed, as set by the `ping -D` option.

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
[Sun Jan 17 22:47:40 2016] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=15.4 ms
[Sun Jan 17 22:47:41 2016] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=14.3 ms
[Sun Jan 17 22:47:42 2016] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=20.0 ms
[Sun Jan 17 22:47:43 2016] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=15.1 ms
[Sun Jan 17 22:47:44 2016] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=12.8 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's somewhat crude, but working solution with `AWK`.

```
ping -c 4 -DO 8.8.8.8 | awk '/^\[/ {gsub(/\[/,"");gsub(/\]/,""); CMD="echo "$1"|date"; system(CMD); for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf(" %s ",$i); printf("\n") } /---/,/rtt min/{print}'
```

Sample output:

```
    $ ping -c 4 -DO 8.8.8.8 | awk '/^\[/ {gsub(/\[/,"");gsub(/\]/,""); CMD="echo "$1"|date"; system(CMD); for(i=2;i<=>
Sun Jan 17 23:24:35 MST 2016
 64  bytes  from  8.8.8.8:  icmp_seq=1  ttl=55  time=44.1  ms 
Sun Jan 17 23:24:36 MST 2016
 64  bytes  from  8.8.8.8:  icmp_seq=2  ttl=55  time=41.6  ms 
Sun Jan 17 23:24:37 MST 2016
 64  bytes  from  8.8.8.8:  icmp_seq=3  ttl=55  time=41.4  ms 
Sun Jan 17 23:24:38 MST 2016
 64  bytes  from  8.8.8.8:  icmp_seq=4  ttl=55  time=49.9  ms 
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 41.470/44.294/49.976/3.455 ms
```